# Linear algebra $ (U^{-1} + I^{-1})^{-1} =M(Y+Y)^{-1}Z $

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on my homework for my Linear Algebra course and I'm having trouble with this question. If anyone could help me I'd be grateful. Thanks.

> Show that if $Z$, $Y$, and $Z+Y$ are nonsingular then: 
>   $ (U^{-1} + I^{-1})^{-1} =M(Y+Y)^{-1}Z $

I know how to get to:
$ (U^{-1} + I^{-1})^{-1} =M(Y+Y)^{-1}Z $

But I don't know how to transform that into: $ (U^{-1} + I^{-1})^{-1} =M(Y+Y)^{-1}Z $

Comment: Please do not change the question after it is solved, so it is easier for future readers to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Y(Y+Z)^{-1}Y+Y(Y+Z)^{-1}Z=Y(Y+Z)^{-1}(Y+Z)=Y$

Answer (score 3):

$$
 Y - Y(Y+Z)^{-1}Y=Y\Big(I-(Y+Z)^{-1}Y\Big)=Y(Y+Z)^{-1}\Big((Y+Z)-Y\Big)=Y(Y+Z)^{-1}Z
$$

Comment: thanks for the help, much appreciated!